# F#: Attempt to memoize member function resets cache on each call?

Tags: caching, f#, member, memoization

I'm trying to memoize a member function of a class, but every time the member is called (by another member) it makes a whole new cache and 'memoized' function.

```
member x.internal_dec_rates = 
        let cache = new Dictionary< Basis*(DateTime option), float*float>()
        fun (basis:Basis) (tl:DateTime option) ->
            match cache.TryGetValue((basis,tl)) with
            | true, (sgl_mux, sgl_lps) -> (sgl_mux, sgl_lps)
            | _ ->
                let (sgl_mux, sgl_lps) =
                    (* Bunch of stuff *)
                cache.Add((basis,tl),(sgl_mux,sgl_lps))
                sgl_mux,sgl_lps
```

I'm using Listing 10.5 in "Real World Functional Programming" as a model. I've tried using a memoization higher-order function and that doesn't help. The above listing has the memoization built in directly.

The problem is, when I call it e.g.

```
member x.px (basis:Basis) (tl: DateTime option) = 
        let (q,l) = (x.internal_dec_rates basis tl)
        let (q2,l2) = (x.internal_dec_rates basis tl)
        (exp -q)*(1.-l)
```

execution goes to the 'let cache=...' line, defeating the whole point. I put in the (q2,l2) line in order to make sure it wasn't a scope problem, but it doesn't seem to be.

In fact I did a test using Petricek's code as a member function and that seems to have the same issue:

```
// Not a member function
let memo1 f =
    let cache = new Dictionary<_,_>()
    (fun x ->
        match cache.TryGetValue(x) with
        | true, v -> v
        | _ -> let v = f x
               cache.Add(x,v)
               v
    )

member x.factorial = memo1(fun y->
    if (y<=0) then 1 else y*x.factorial(y-1))
```

Even the internal recursion of x.factorial seems to set up a new 'cache' for each level.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make this work?

Comment: You may also wish to consider using ConcurrentDictionary if there is any chance your code will be run in parallel.  Plain Dictionary can fail in these circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to your comment on Jack's answer, this doesn't have to become tedious. Given a memoize function:

```ml
let memoize f =
  let cache = Dictionary()
  fun x ->
    match cache.TryGetValue(x) with
    | true, v -> v
    | _ -> 
      let v = f x
      cache.Add(x, v)
      v
```

Define each of your functions as let-bound values and return them from your methods:

```ml
type T() as x =
  let internalDecRates = memoize <| fun (basis: Basis, tl: DateTime option) ->
    (* compute result *)
    Unchecked.defaultof<float * float>

  let px = memoize <| fun (basis, tl) ->
    let (q,l) = x.InternalDecRates(basis, tl)
    let (q2,l2) = x.InternalDecRates(basis, tl)
    (exp -q)*(1.-l)

  member x.InternalDecRates = internalDecRates
  member x.Px = px
```

The only "boilerplate" is the `let` binding and call to `memoize`.

EDIT: As kvb noted, in F# 3.0 auto-properties allow a more concise solution:

```ml
type T() as x =
  member val InternalDecRates = memoize <| fun (basis: Basis, tl: DateTime option) ->
    (* compute result *)
    Unchecked.defaultof<float * float>

  member val Px = memoize <| fun (basis, tl) ->
    let (q,l) = x.InternalDecRates(basis, tl)
    let (q2,l2) = x.InternalDecRates(basis, tl)
    (exp -q)*(1.-l)
```

Answer (score 5):

I see a lot of long answers here; the short answer is that

```
member x.P = code()
```

defines a property `P` which has a *getter* that runs `code()` every time `P` is accessed.  You need to move the cache creation into the class's constructor, so that it will only run once.

Answer (score 4):

As others already said, this cannot be done just by defining a single `member` in F# 2.0. You either need a separate field (`let` bound value) for a cache or for a local function that is memoized.

As mentioned by kvb, in F# 3.0, you can do this using `member val` which is a property that is initialized when the object is created (and has an automatically generated backing field where the result is stored). Here is a complete sample that demonstrates this (it will work in Visual Studio 2012):

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Test() = 
  /// Property that is initialized when the object is created
  /// and stores a function value 'int -> int'
  member val Foo = 
    // Initialize cache and return a function value
    let cache = Dictionary<int, int>()
    fun arg ->
      match cache.TryGetValue(arg) with
      | true, res -> res
      | false, _ -> 
          let res = arg * arg
          printfn "calculating %d" arg
          cache.Add(arg, res)
          res
    // Part of the property declaration that instructs
    // the compiler to generate getter for the property
    with get
```

The `with get` part of the declaration can be omitted, but I include it here to make the sample clearer (you can also use `with get, set` to get a mutable property). Now you can call `test.Foo` as a function and it caches the value as required

```
let t = Test()
t.Foo(10)
t.Foo(10)
```

The only problem with this approach is that `t.Foo` is actually compiled as a property that returns a function (instead of being compiled as a method). This is not a big problem when you use the class from F#, but it would be a problem if you were calling it from C# (because C# would see the member as a property of type `FSharpFunc<int, int>`, which is hard to use).

Answer (score 2):

John is correct -- you need to move the `cache` dictionary into a private, let-bound member of the type.

Type members are compiled a bit differently than `let`-bound values in modules, which is the reason for the difference in behavior. If you copy/paste the body of your `x.internal_dec_rates` method and assign it to a `let`-bound value in a module, it *should* work correctly then, because the F# compiler will compile it as a closure which gets created once and then assigned to a `static readonly` field of the module.

A couple of other tips, for good measure:

- Type `member` methods can use optional parameters -- so you can slightly simplify the method signature if you like.
- You can create the cache key just once and reuse it (this also helps avoid mistakes).
- You can simplify the `(sgl_mux, sgl_lps)` pattern-matching code by just assigning the tuple a name (e.g., `value`), since you're just returning the whole tuple anyway.

Here's my take on your code:

```
type FooBar () =
    let cache = new Dictionary< Basis*(DateTime option), float*float>()

    member x.internal_dec_rates (basis : Basis, ?tl : DateTime) =
        let key = basis, tl
        match cache.TryGetValue key with
        | true, value -> value
        | _ ->
            // sgl_mux, sgl_lps
            let value =
                (* Bunch of stuff *)

            cache.Add (key, value)
            value
```

Comment: OK thanks I guess I have to go down this route. It's a pity because I have a lot of member functions, which will each need their own cache. I can see that becoming messy. I liked the closure approach as it kept everything very succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the dictionary outside the function call - like

```
let cache = new Dictionary< Basis*(DateTime option), float*float>()
member x.internal_dec_rates =             
        fun (basis:Basis) (tl:DateTime option) ->
            match cache.TryGetValue((basis,tl)) with
            | true, (sgl_mux, sgl_lps) -> (sgl_mux, sgl_lps)
            | _ ->
                let (sgl_mux, sgl_lps) =
                    (* Bunch of stuff *)
                cache.Add((basis,tl),(sgl_mux,sgl_lps))
                sgl_mux,sgl_lps
```

This way the cache persists across the function calls.  Your `memo1` has the same problem.  In the original version, you create a new cache every time you call the function, this way we just have a single cache, which persists across function calls.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, note that in F# 3.0 you can use automatically implemented properties, which will behave as you want:

```
member val internal_dec_rates = ...
```

Here, the right hand side is evaluated only once, but everything is self-contained.