# How best to memoize based on argument only, not function closure, and inside a class?

Tags: dictionary, f#, reference, memoization

*(question edited and rewritten to reflect chat discussion results)*

In one line: Given a state in a state monad, evaluate monadic function once, cache the results.

I am trying to cache the result of a function evaluation, where the key of the cache is the state of a State monad, and where I do not care about possible side effects: i.e., even if the body of the function may change in theory, I know it will be independent of the state:

```
f x = state { return DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(x) }
g x = state { return DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(x) }
```

Here, `g 10` and `f 10` should yield the same result, they may not differ as result to a double call to `DateTime.Now`, i.e., they *must* be deterministic. For the sake of argument, the variable state here is `x`.

On a same token, `(g 10) - (f 5)` should yield *exactly* `5 minutes` and not a microsecond more or less.

---

After finding out that caching didn't work, I toned down a more elaborate solution to its bare minimum, using [Don Syme's memoization pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx) with maps (or dict).

The memoization pattern:

```
module Cache =
    let cache f = 
        let _cache = ref Map.empty
        fun x ->
        match (!_cache).TryFind(x) with
        | Some res -> res
        | None ->
             let res = f x
             _cache := (!_cache).Add(x,res)
             res
```

The caching is supposed to be used as part of a computation builder, in the Run method:

```
type someBuilder() =
    member __.Run f = 
        Log.time "Calling __.Run"
        let memo_me =
            fun state ->
                let res = 
                    match f with
                    | State expr - expr state
                    | Value v -> state, v
                Log.time ("Cache miss, adding key: %A", s)
                res

        XCache.cache memo_me
```

This doesn't work, because the cache function is different each time because of the closure, resulting in hitting a cache miss each time over. It should be independent of `expr` above, and dependent on `state` only.

---

I tried placing the `_cache` outside the cache function on module level, but then it hits the problem of generalization:

> Value restriction. The value '_cache' has been inferred to have generic type
>   Either define '_cache' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Which I then tried to solve using type annotations, but I ended up not being able to use it in the generic function for the same reason: it required specific type annotations then to be used:

```
let _cache<'T, 'U when 'T: comparison> ref : Map<'T, 'U>  = ref Map.empty
```

### Edit, a working version of the whole computation builder

Here's the computation builder as asked in the comments, tested in FSI. The caching should be dependent solely on `TState`, not on the whole of `'TState -> 'TState * 'TResult`.

```
type State<'TState, 'TResult> = State of ('TState -> 'TState * 'TResult)

type ResultState<'TState, 'TResult> =
    | Expression of State<'TState, 'TResult>
    | Value of 'TResult

type RS<'S, 'T> = ResultState<'S, 'T>

type RS =
    static member run v s =
        match v with
        | Value item -> s, item
        | Expression (State expr) -> expr s

    static member bind k v =
        match v with
        | Expression (State expr) ->
            Expression
            <|  State
               (fun initialState ->
                let updatedState, result = expr initialState
                RS.run (k result) updatedState
               )
        | Value item -> k item

type MyBuilder() =
    member __.Bind (e, f) = RS.bind f e    
    member __.Return v = RS.Value v    
    member __.ReturnFrom e = e    
    member __.Run f = 
        printfn "Running!"
        // add/remove the first following line to see it with caching
        XCache.cache <|
            fun s ->
            match f with
            | RS.Expression (State state) -> 
                printfn "Call me once!"
                state s
            | RS.Value v -> s, v

module Builders =
    let builder = new MyBuilder()

    // constructing prints "Running!", this is as expected
    let create() = builder {
            let! v = RS.Expression <| (State <| fun i -> (fst i + 12.0, snd i + 3), "my value")
            return "test " + v
        }

    // for seeing the effect, recreating the builder twice, 
    // it should be cached once
    let result1() = create()(30.0, 39)
    let result2() = create()(30.0, 39)
```

Result of running the example in FSI:

> Running!
>   Call me once!
>   val it : (float * int) * string = ((42.0, 42), "test my value")
>   Call me once!
>   val it : (float * int) * string = ((42.0, 42), "test my value")

Comment: The way you have set this up, the cache isn't stored anywhere between runs.  You will need to create a local variable in the class.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: it seems that whatever way I am trying to turn it, I either run into generics-issue (_"The expression was expected to have type `obj` but here has `'a * 'b`"_, or something similar saying that `(int * int)` does not support `IComparable`). I heed your advice, but I can't find a way to make it work, it seems that the generics is killed as soon as I try to use a let-statement at module level to capture the memoizable functions. It is similar to this, but not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845285/f-attempt-to-memoize-member-function-resets-cache-on-each-call?rq=1

Comment: Can you provide code that uses the computation builder?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I'll try to create a manageable and sizable example.

Comment: My running theory so far is that you're actually making multiple calls to `Run` instead of making just one call and then calling the result repeatedly. But let's see the example.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I've added the computation builder, I hope it's enough to illustrate its workings, ideas. I have deliberately split the `run` for the binding and the `run` for the CU starter, as I only want to cache the whole of one CU and not intermediate results, which wouldn't add much.

Comment: Why the `ref` keyword?

Comment: @Abel My mistake, I didn't read to the end. :)

Comment: I see your computation builder, but I don't see `Cache` used anywhere in it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fyodor, the first code snippet shows how I tried to use cache.

Comment: But this is useless this way: you don't show a complete example of something that is supposed to work, but doesn't. The first sample is supposed to work from the looks of it, but there may be a mistake in consuming code. The last sample is not supposed to work in the first place, so there is no problem there.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, sorry, deleted my last comments, they were night-time infused confusing.. I updated the question. The crux is that I would like the cache to behave on a per-class, not a per-instance basis.

Comment: You can certainly "keep" the cache dictionary per-class instead of per-instance, but that would be useless, because the function `f` that is being memoized only appears per-instance. You can't memoize function `f` at a level higher than you get hold of it. Makes sense?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, yes, that makes sense, and that's _exactly_ the core of the issue. Since the result of `f` is only dependent on `state`, same state in, regardless of closure, should yield same output. My idea was (futile so far) to have the cache be dependent only on `state`, not on the per-instance occurrence of `f`, but using this pattern creates a per-instance cache, even if I make the `_cache` itself global.

Comment: But `state` is a function, isn't it? Are you saying that you expect to only ever have a limited number of these functions and not allow the consumer to make new ones?

Comment: No, I can clearly see that new `state` is created on every `bind` call. So since that's the case, how do you expect to ever see the same `state` twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95974/discussion-between-abel-and-fyodor-soikin).

Answer (score 2):

Just add the Cache into the Run

```
member __.Run f = 
    printfn "Running!"

    Cache.cache <|

        fun s ->
        match f with
        | RS.Expression (State state) -> 
            printfn "Call me once!"
            state s
        | RS.Value v -> s, v
```

and modify the cache function to see if it really caches

```
module Cache =
    let cache f = 
        let _cache = ref Map.empty
        fun x ->
            match (!_cache).TryFind(x) with
            | Some res -> printfn "from cache";  res
            | None ->
                 let res = f x
                 _cache := (!_cache).Add(x,res)
                 printfn "to cache"
                 res
```

and the output is

```
Call me once!
to cache
val it : (float * int) * string = ((42.0, 42), "test my value")

> 
from cache
val it : (float * int) * string = ((42.0, 42), "test my value")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems that the `Cache.cache <|` backwards pipe operator takes care of the type issues I had with my first example, I should've known. I also see now where it goes wrong: in the "bigger picture", many builders are created with the same main argument (i.e., same closure), but since these are created in different places they end up being different objects, ending up running `Run` and `Delay` for each object, and of course, each having its own cache. Now the trick is to have the cache operate on the state, and be independent of the object. That I am failing to achieve.

Comment: Actually, only one builder is created, unless you're calling `new Builder()` many times, which you certainly don't have to do, you can use the same instance for all computations.